# How can I configure the sencha app build command to add files like webconfig , service.asmx to build folder

Tags: extjs, extjs4

How can I add misc files like the BIN folder in asp.net and webconfig using the sencha app build command ?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to create a "template" app with the required additional documents and override the `starter` parameter to the path of the "template" app.  The [sencha cmd reference](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/3.1.2/#!/guide/command_reference-section-sencha-generate-app) has more details about `sencha generate app`

Comment: I've seen templates related to sencha architect. I'm using ExtJS with sencha cmd. is it the same ?